# What is wrong with this counter (if-statement)? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, counter

I tried to loop threw an array in order to count the occurance of 'phone1'.
The Data from the backend has the following structure:

```
[{
    Key: 'phone1',
    Recording: {
      ID: 'phone1',
      Tel: '1000',
      User: 'Maria',
      Price: '350',
      docType: 'asset'
    }]
```

My function for this looks like:

```
backendData.list[0].map((phone, i) => {
            var counter = 0;
             for (var i = 0; i < backendData.length; i++) {
                if (backendData[i].Key === 'phone1') counter++;
             }
             console.log(counter);
          });
```

The result I get is always 0, but it has to be 1 with my Data.

Comment: First you don't need to use .map function you can use .forEach because map returns an array.

Second. Do you have a list of lists? Or why you try to do .list[0], I think you are trying to access to backendData.list

Third, You have to correct this var i = 0; i < backendData.length; i++ to var i = 0; i < backendData.length - 1; i++ . Remember that lists start in index 0.

Last, I don't understand your if. Can you put your JSON?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let counter = 0;
backendData.list[0].forEach((phone, i) => {
   if(phone.Key === 'phone1') counter++;
   console.log(counter);
})
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but after a reload the following Error occurs:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') referring to this line: backendData.list[0].forEach((phone, i) => {

Comment: @wizi2022 I need to know how it looks your json

Comment: I get the data from my API (Express JS), so i have no json file.

Comment: Add me on discord and I Will explain you. If you want  Oscar Gonzalez#0487

Answer (score 0):

You just can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to count objects by condition:

```js
const backendData = [{Key:'phone1',Recording:{ID:'phone1',Tel:'1000',User:'Maria',Price:'350',docType:'asset'}}];

const result = backendData
  .filter(({ Key }) => Key === 'phone1')
  .length;

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```